# change images onclick a link Angular

Tags: angular, image, click

I want to have a possibility to go forwards and backwards through images, like in an album. I want a back and a forwards button to realise this in Angular.

```html
<img
  id="AlbumImage1" " src="AlbumImage1.jpg" />
<img
  id="AlbumImage2" " src="AlbumImage2.jpg"  />
<img
  id="AlbumImage3" " src="AlbumImage2.jpg" />


<a>
<img
  id="forwardImage" (click)="changeAlbumImageForward()" src=".jpg" /></a>
```

**.ts**

```js
changeAlbumImageForward(){
    (document.getElementById('AlbumImage') as HTMLImageElement).src = 'assets/AlbumImage1.png';
}
```

How can I realise this in Angular, is there a good tutorial for this?

My code is wrong and doesn't work, so appreciate help.

Comment: All of your `img` elements have the same id, which is invalid in HTML. You should consider using an array of image sources and use that as a basis for binding an image's src attribute to a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about binding the src of your image? Something like:

```
<img [src]="imageSource" >

<img src="forwardImage" (click)="changeAlbumImageForward()">
```

and in your ts:

```
imageSource: string = 'some/image/path';

changeAlbumchangeAlbumImageForward() {
   this.imageSource = 'some/new/image/path';
}
```